# Get growth by when having running-difference

Tags: cognos

May I have your advice how can I get the growth % with Running-Difference?

I am working on a relational package.
By using Filter, i extraction the revenue on 201412 and 201507.
By using running-difference, I got the difference between the two months.

running-difference ([Revenue] for [Application Type], [Branch])

However I cant figure out how can I get the growth since I cant determine the BASE (which is the revenue in 201412) from a relational package.

I want to avoid creating another query which is just to retrieve the 201412 revenue and then later on join to my working query for the Base purpose.
Please advice..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question right, but try to create a new data item that will hold the running-total for revenue, then deduct your current data item to get the prev month's value. See attached file for a sample data. You can now use prev month rev value in computing growth.

[prev month rev] = [running-total(revenue)] - revenue

[image]

Hope it helps.
Cheers! :)